# Add +1 to a string obtained from another site

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I have a string I get from a website.

A portion of the string is "X2" I want to add +1 to 2.

The entire string I get is:

```
20120815_00_X2
```

What I want is to add the "X2" +1 until "20120815_00_X13"

Comment: Do you know that you will always be getting `X2` at the end? Why not do a `str_replace` to increment it?

Comment: At the end split the string and use a While to increase the number. As follows:  
  @$string  = ereg_replace('_T2', '', $string ); 
 $i = 2;
while ($i < 13) {
 echo $string  . '_T' . $i . '.gif' . '<br />'  ;
$i++;
}

Comment: @Bcl00 Note that `ereg_replace` is deprecated and that you can do it in 1 line with the regex from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
$string = '20120815_00_X2';

$concat = substr($string, 0, -1);
$num = (integer) substr($string, -1);

$incremented = $concat . ($num + 1);

echo $incremented;
```

For more informations about substr() see => [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: What if it's `$string = '20120815_00_X10';`?

Comment: then he will need to use -2 :|

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the number at the end of your string and capture it, test for a maximum value of `12` and add one if that's the case, so your pattern would look something like:

```
/(\d+)$/    // get all digits at the end
```

and the whole expression:

```
$new = preg_replace('/(\d+)$/e', "($1 < 13) ? ($1 + 1) : $1", $original);
```

I have used the `e` modifier so that the replacement expression will be evaluated as php code.

See the working example at [CodePad](http://codepad.org/6TDc0U6j).

Answer (score 1):

This solution works (no matter what the number after X is):

```
function myCustomAdd($string)
{

$original = $string;

$new = explode('_',$original);

$a = end($new);

$b = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $a);

$c = $b + 1;

$letters = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z,.]/", '', $a);

$d = $new[0].'_'.$new[1].'_'.$letters.$c;

return $d;

}

var_dump(myCustomAdd("20120815_00_X13"));
```

Output:

```
string(15) "20120815_00_X14"
```