# I try to use variable in SQL statement, I have tried mysql_real_escape_string but still fail

Tags: php, sql

The error I got is:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gz_01' in 'where clause''**

This is my original code:

```
    // $universityID would be column name like gz_01, gz_02, wh_01, wh_02...etc...
    // value in gz_01 column is int type
    $universityID = "gz_01";

    addSubscription($universityID);

    function addSubscription($university){

    Here I skip the codes of connection to SQL

    // count the subscription
    $sql = "UPDATE qr_code_count
            SET $university = $university + 1
            ";                      

    $pdo->exec($sql);
    }
```

But the value in gz_01 does not add 1 for each addSubscription() call.

When I used **$sql = "UPDATE qr_code_count SET gz_01 = gz_01 + 1"** my codes worked as expected, the value in gz_01 add one for each addSubscription() call.

I searched for answer on stackoverflow and found a possible solution of using mysql_real_escape_string(), but still my codes failed.

Can anyone give me a pointer on what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: 1)What exact values of $university are You using ? (only gz_01 ? )

2)Do you get any error ?

Comment: Have You tried wraping the field name with ` characters ? Its propably because the '_' character parsed in some awkward way by MYSQL engine.

Comment: This might be outta context here, but can you try to close the SQL in the same line?

Comment: @Uriziel, the values are gz_01, gz_02, wh_01, wh_02...etc. I did not get any error, really puzzled me. The problem seems to be the SQL statement is not correct when using a variable. But I have not figured out how to fix it.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: That query should work as-is, since `gz_01` is not a MySQL reserved word. Can you make a complete, minimal example demonstrating the problem? Also, check for errors on all database calls.

Comment: If you run `UPDATE qr_code_count SET \`gz_01\`= \`gz_01\` + 1` directly in the database (say through phpMyAdmin, Sequel Pro), does it work?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971310/add-1-to-a-string-obtained-from-another-site

Comment: Could it be that $university is not a numeric but a CHAR value? You clearly refer to an ID and the field name you want to update is $university. Or you forgot the WHERE statement.

Comment: Just an advice: don't use [deprecated](http://nl1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) functions! Use the MySQLi extension instead. And look at this comment for the function: [mysql_set_charset](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php#86455)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have database table that looks like this with one row?

```
|  z_01  |  gz_02  |  wh_01  |  wh_02  |
|   0    |    1    |    3    |    4    |
```

Why not make the table so it makes sense?

```
|  university_id  |  qr_code_count  |
|      z_01       |       0         |
|      gz_02      |       1         |
|      wh_01      |       3         |
|      wh_02      |       4         |
```

Then you'd update very simply with less change of errors:

```
function addSubscription($uniId){

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE qr_code_count
                           SET qr_code_count = qr_code_count + 1
                           WHERE university_id = :university_id");

    $stmt->bindParam(':university_id', $uniId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->exec($sql);
}

$universityID = "gz_01";

addSubscription($universityID);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
$sql = 'UPDATE qr_code_count SET `'.$university.'` = `'.$university.'` + 1';
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to write is as: `$sql = 'UPDATE qr_code_count SET \`$university\` = \`$university\` + 1';` ?

Comment: using simple quotes won't read `$university` as a variable but as a string so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increase the id by one if it is set to auto_increment in your database table  but then you will have to get rid of the "gz_" part in your id.

Comment: 1)You can only have 1 auto_increment per table 2)Sometimes you dont ALWAYS want to increment the value, so its not an correct answer to the question in my opinion.

Comment: You could write a function which could split the id into string and number. Then increment the number by one final join the string and the incremented value and get this value inserted into the table.

Comment: Indeed I (and post author) could do that. But how is that easier or better from his current attempt ?

Comment: Because in this you are incrementing a string (gz_01) by 1.

Comment: Do we both see the same query there ? @Dennisboys trying to incremet **value** of **column** of name gz_01 not the value 'gz_01' .

OK nvm, lets just hold on to the topic right there, thank You.

Comment: That's what Uriziel, I believe, he will get the value of the field gz_01 as 'gz_01+1' (as it is).

Comment: And that why he should escape the field name with standard '`' character which is recognized (should) by MYSQL parser as field name and not splitted in some funny way like now.

Comment: Or is it that he wants the id to look like 'gz_01+1'. @ Dennisboys: Is this what you intend?

Comment: So just by surrounding the fieldname gz_01 with "`" would make the id increment by 1. Is this what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE qr_code_count
        SET :columnName1 = :columnName2 + 1
        ";                      
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':columnName1', $universityID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':columnName2', $universityID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your university is always in format `gz_01, gz_02, wh_01, wh_02...etc...` 
letter letter undescore and  to digits. code below will do the magic.

```
  function addSubscription($university){
    $universitySub = $university[0].$university[1].$university[2];
    $universityNumberInc = ($university[3].$university[4]+1);
    if(strlen($universityNumberInc) < 2) { $universityNumberInc = "0".$universityNumberInc;}
    $universityinc =  $universitySub.$universityNumberInc;

$sql = "UPDATE qr_code_count
            SET $university = $universityinc;
            ";                      

    $pdo->exec($sql);
    }
```

Image before and after +1 to `$university`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if $university = 'gh_01'
get only number from above string using below code
$num = intval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $university ));
$num=$num+1;
get only letters
$letter=preg_replace('/[0-9]/','',$university);
$unversity=$letter.'_'.$num; // combine both letter and number
$sql = "UPDATE qr_code_count SET '".$university."' = "'.$university."'";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('prenium');
$university="property_id";
$sql = 'UPDATE property_images
        SET '.$university.' = '.$university.'+1'; 

if(mysql_query($sql)) echo "DONE !";
else die(mysql_error());
```

I have tested this and it's working with me

**EDITED**

Comment: Hi Jeffery, I tried your method, but still got the error of Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gz_01' in 'where clause''